# ValueError: [E109] Component 'tagger' could not be run. Did you forget to call `initialize()`?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spacy, bert-language-model

I use jupyter notebook for writing code, but our team wants me to write code using visual studio code so we can do version control and merges in Git. I set up my environment with new versions of python libraries and anaconda.

When I pip installed BERT, spacy, anaconda, sqlachemy, and other libraries for my python scripts, I received this unknown error: ValueError: [E109] Component 'tagger' could not be run. Did you forget to call `initialize()`?

My script worked with jupyter notebook, by the way. When I uninstalled spacy, and ran my NLP script, I got the same error. Does anyone know how I can fix this error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After searching a lot, I found it was related to the internal dependency of spacy - `"thinc"`
You need to downgrade the version of `thinc==8.0.8` if you are having `spacy==3.0.x`

try running :

```
pip install --upgrade thinc==8.0.8
```